# How to implement asynchronous training with batch normalization use distributed tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, distributed, batch-normalization

I want to train a deep neural network with **batch normalization** use **asynchronous training of distributed tensorflow**. But I do not how to keep track of mean, variance, offset and scale. Can anyone give some idea? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Ethan. I have same problem. Di d you solve it

Comment: I refer to the [official inceptionv3 example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/9b57f41ce21cd7264c52140c9ab31cdfc5169fcd/research/inception/inception/inception_distributed_train.py), and it is fine for me.